# OAauth2- Use The Implicit Flow Where Backend Server Is Same As Authorization Server

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid

I understand that is not recommended to use the implicit flow anymore, but I think that in my case I should use (But i'm not sure).  Our system is still small and our resource server is not separated from the authorization server. When a user is logging into the site, he provides his credentials (user name & password) using a post request where the response is the IdToken & Access Token & Refresh Token. it seems to me that in the case I should use the implicit flow.

Comment: You say you have a resource server and an authorization server, and they are conjoined. The "site" that you are talking about though sounds more like a "client" (in the OAuth sense of the word). The API that this Web site calls isn't part of this pair, is it? That's separate, right? I ask because the "API" would be the "resource server" and the "site" would be the "client". If you can clarify, I (or someone else) can give you are more accurate/helpful answer.